# AWS console doesn't show ecs tasks properly

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ecs

I have ran a ecs task using fargate under a ecs service, and I am pretty sure that the task is running and accessible. However, if I press refresh button many times, aws console sometimes doesn't show the task properly (see the picture), sometimes does.
[image]
This issue also happens randomly and frequently when I use python boto3 to list the task. Sometimes it returns 1 task and somtimes it returns 0 task.

```
ecs_client = boto3.client("ecs")
ecs_client.list_tasks(cluster_name="my_cluster", serviceName="my_service")
```

Does anyone have the same issue?

NOTE:
I select the filter to show all tasks, but it still shows nothing.
[image]

Comment: By default, `list_tasks` only returns running tasks. From the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs/client/list_tasks.html): *The default status filter is RUNNING, which shows tasks that Amazon ECS has set the desired status to RUNNING.*

Comment: I'm sure that my task is running. I cannot found it on aws console nor boto3

Comment: It might have failed. Check the other statuses

Comment: Can you select a different filter in that "Running tasks" dropdown and see if it shows up elsewhere, and with what status?

Comment: As the picture I updated, It shows nothing when the filter is set to `All tasks`.

Comment: Actually, I have the aws console issue for a long time. I always ignore it until I have the same issue with boto3. I'm not sure that they have the same root cause.